# Touch Input in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm doing a simple board game in unity. My process is that when I press a button, the program will generate a random number from 1-9 and my character will change position from his initial position to the next position depending on what is the resulted number.

My process works fine. My character moves the way it should, but I have a small problem in my touch input. When I press my button, it will generate a number and show it in a GUIText for JUST A MILLISECOND and then it will change back again to 0 when I let go of my button. I think my problem is that the resulted number only appears in the GUIText when I hold the button and comes back to 0 when I let go. And that is not only the problem the other problem is that when I hold my button longer it keeps on generating and accepting numbers so it totally messes up my process. My question is how can I prevent my button from processing after just ONE click and how can I show the resulted number in my GUIText after the click. I've experimented on my if statement changing it to different Touch Phase properties but still I can't get it right. Here is my code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class dice_roll : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture2D roll_btn;
public Texture2D roll_btn2;
public static int num = 0;
public static string num_str = "";
public GUIText move_number;
public static int character_position = 0;
public static float y_axis = 1.18f;
public GameObject character;
public GameObject i;
public GameObject ii;
public GameObject iii;
public GameObject iv;
public GameObject v;
public GameObject vi;
public GameObject vii;
public GameObject viii;
public GameObject ix;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    guiTexture.texture = roll_btn;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    move_number.text = "0";

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) 
    {
        if (guiTexture.HitTest(touch.position))
        {
            num = Random.Range(1,10);
            guiTexture.texture = roll_btn2;
            num_str = num.ToString();
            move_number.text = num_str;
            character_position = character_position + num;
            switch (character_position) 
            {
                case 1 : 
                    //character.transform.position = i.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (i.transform.position.x, y_axis, i.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    character.transform.position = ii.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (ii.transform.position.x, y_axis, ii.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    //character.transform.position = iii.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (iii.transform.position.x, y_axis, iii.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    //character.transform.position = iv.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (iv.transform.position.x, y_axis, iv.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    //character.transform.position = v.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (v.transform.position.x, y_axis, v.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    //character.transform.position = vi.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (vi.transform.position.x, y_axis, vi.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 7 :
                    //character.transform.position = vii.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (vii.transform.position.x, y_axis, vii.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 8 :
                    //character.transform.position = vii.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (viii.transform.position.x, y_axis, viii.transform.position.z);
                    break;
                case 9 :
                    //character.transform.position = vii.transform.position;
                    character.transform.position = new Vector3 (ix.transform.position.x, y_axis, ix.transform.position.z);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
   }
```

My GUITexture `roll_btn` is the button I'm pressing. So the problem that I was referring to is that my integer `character_position` keeps on adding values from the generated numbers while I'm holding the button. I want to prevent that.

Thank you in advanced. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Update()` method is called once per frame and you are setting your value to zero on 
every frame in here 
`void Update () 
{
    move_number.text = "0";
}`
so by removing this it should work fine